# Не правильный вывод содержания списка телеграм ботом

Tags: python, telebot, бот

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот написал итератор для вывода телеграм ботом значений из списка в чат.
Тестил на одном устройстве, всё работало, но когда решил проверить работоспособность с нескольких устройств(с трёх), выводит не так, как нужно.
Cмысл в том, что бот должен выводить поочерёдно элементы списка с помощью next().

```
def films_comedy():
    for item in list_comedy:
        yield item

elif message.text == 'Комедия':
    img = open(f'.\\bot\\forbot\\imagescomedy\\{next(phototosend_comedy)}.jpg',
                'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'{next(filmtosend_comedy)}')
```

Но при использовании с нескольких устройств он просто в любом случае выводит следующий элемент списка.
Как мне для каждого пользователя инициализировать бота отдельно, чтобы пользователи не влияли на ux других пользователей?
Использую библиотеку PyTelegramBotAPI